# Can't get user's current location

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I have a simple goal of my app that is get the current coordinate, and  use them to add an annotation on the mapview.

I have been tried lots of solution from google results, but its still not working....

The debug area never shows "locationManager did UpdateLocation", the message what I print in function....

It's seems like the app never run "did UpdateLocation" function, even startUpdatingLocation() has been called?

---

Add location privacy string in info.plist : Done.

Turn on the GPS on my Mac Pro : Done.

Xcode version : 10.1

MacOS : 10.13.6 (High Sierra)

---

```
let cloaction = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    MapView.delegate = self
    MapView.showsScale = true
    MapView.showsPointsOfInterest = true
    MapView.showsUserLocation = true

    cloaction.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    cloaction.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        print("IN")

        cloaction.delegate = self
        cloaction.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        cloaction.startUpdatingLocation()
    }        
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    print("locationManager did UpdateLocation")

    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (locations.first?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (locations.first?.coordinate.longitude)!)

    currentLat = (locations.first?.coordinate.latitude)!
    currentLon = (locations.first?.coordinate.longitude)!

    let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01)

    MapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(currentLat,currentLon), span: span), animated: true)
    MapView.showsUserLocation = true

    print(locations.first?.coordinate.latitude)
    print(locations.first?.coordinate.longitude)

}
```

Comment: Add a tag for your development platform.

Comment: Add the following to viewDidLoad.  cloaction.delegate = self

Comment: You are debugging with Simulation? How about debug with device?

Comment: @Simon are you sure the name of the delegate is correct?? Also try updating your method name to `func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])` note the `_` before `manager`

Comment: Kosuke Ogawa:Yes, I was debugging with Simulation..., and follow your sugestion, I don't know how to debug with device....

Comment: iOSer: Thank you, but it's still not show the print("....") message, it seems doesn't run the function.

Comment: Just checking does print("IN") run? If it does then I suggest you try running this on the phone. From experience gps data needs to be run on phone. Unless the latest macs have gps it won't run because you are on simulator.
Also make sure you added Privacy request in info.plist

Comment: Alexander: Ok, it's seems to be debug the app on the phone is better.

Answer (score 0):

Have you `import CoreLocation`?

Start with making a variable `let myLocation = CLLocation()`

Instead of have so much in viewDidLoad you can make a function and call the mLocation in viewDidLoad instead :

```
func mLocation(){
    cloaction.delegate = self
    cloaction.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    cloaction.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(){
        cloaction.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

And thats all you need for the `clocation`

LocationManager could also be updated

```
 func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:[CLLocation]){
        let newLocation = locations[0]

        print("\(myLocation.coordinate.latitude)")
        print("\(myLocation.coordinate.longitude)")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the reason is very simple: You  call the `didUpdateLocation` mehthod wich is only called when you change your location. Your Mac is on certain place and dont move so thats why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! finally... thank your answering, it's really need to run on device, thanks  Kosuke Ogawa's suggestion, and every one's guide, I am a new to learn swift, and first time ask question here, it's fun, thank you every one.
(But I don't know how to accept a answer if the answer is a comment? Someone teach me how do that?)

Comment: you should not write stuff like this in the answers section, save it for the comments, and to accept the answer click on the gray check mark (√) below the downvote button on the left of the answer, then it should become green.